# How to query in impala SQL in python function effectively

Tags: python, pandas, impala

Basically, my company using apache impala for datamart, I guess it no different with non-hadoop SQL

connection args are define before and connection is define as `conn = connect(host=host_name, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)`

Everytime I need a table I need to call a function like this

```
def impala_connection(host, port, user, password, database):
    conn = connect(host=host_name, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from table1')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
table1 = pd.DataFrame(impala_connection(host_name, port, user,password, database))
```

For another table I also do this

```
def impala_connection(host, port, user, password, database):
    conn = connect(host=host_name, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from table2')
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
table2 = pd.DataFrame(impala_connection(host_name, port, user,password, database))
```

etc.

Is there any more "elegant" way doing this, I try multiple way to less repetition from the function, here's my maximum result. Since function is desiged to call once and used multiple times not other way around.

Comment: You could pass the execute string in as a parameter.

Comment: will try @Scott Boston

Comment: Why not use `pd.read_sql`?